# Inserting google ads between posts in a wordpress site with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, infinite-scroll, adsense

I am trying to insert google ads between every 5 posts in my wordpress site with infinite 
scroll.

This is the code I am using to add the google ads between every 5 posts

```
if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    //before 
    if (($count>1) && ($count%5 == 0) ){ ?>
      <div>
        [adcode] 
      </div> 
   <? }
    $count++;
```

The code works for first sets of posts loaded but it does not work with infinite scroll.
The infinite scroll loads the next set of posts without the google ad.

This is the site i am working with http://bluehandwebdesign.com/dev/hk/

This is the reference site http://terra.com/

Can you help?

Comment: Having this same issue but I'm using custom image ads though. Does anyone know of a way to add divs after the first page of an infinite scroll website?

Answer (score 1):

Is far as I know: 
You are not allowed to do this. There is a maximum of 3 ads per page and you don't want your account suspened :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply. Currently i am displaying 6 posts per page and only one ad in between those 6 posts. The additional posts are loaded through infinite scroll plugin which takes the next page url. Do you think this will also qualify against google ad terms?

Comment: Everything is ok as long as you have a maximum of 3 ads per page. It doesn't matter how much content you load dynamically. And I think (but I'm not sure) it is prohibited to create and destroy ads so you always have a maximum of 3 ads.